# How to set ASP.NET identity schema

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want all the ASP.NET Identity tables to reside in a schema called `identity`.

My `DefaultConnection` connects with a username of it's own, which is a member of an `identity` role which in tun has ownership of an `identity` schema.

When I run the site though, I get `The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.`

How can I limit Identity to using and having access to a specific schema?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529291/asp-net-identity-use-custom-schema

Comment: Yup, it's a duplicate!  Thanks.