# Reusing ASP.NET Identity System in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

We have a couple of applications build using .NET Framework and ASP.NET Identity System.

Now, we would like to create all new apps using ASP.NET Core and reuse the existing database and schema i.e. ASP.NET Identity System.

One solution which I think should work is by managing login/account activity in separate application.

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up SSO using WS-Federation [3] by creating a STS [1] which your ASP.NET Core applications use as authentication provider [2].

[1] http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/08/08/using-single-sign-on-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-mvc-net/

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-ws-federation-as-an-external-login-provider-for-aspnet-core-identity

[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adfsod/e280606c-8bbc-4800-bf3b-7f14fbe9e21c

Comment: i am looking for in-app solution

Comment: Is [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2) an option? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878000/how-to-migrate-identity-users-from-a-mvc5-app-to-a-asp-net-core-2-2-app.