# Identity Server 3 to 4 use of AspUser passwords

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I've upgraded a project using IdentityServer 3 to the current version 4.3

As one of the things I've copied all data from the 3 version to the 4 version of the DB.

It looks like all password need to be set again by the users.

Can I convert the password from the 3.o version so they work in the 4.3 version or did I forget something which makes these password invalid.

Comment: Do you migrate asp.net idenity to asp.net core identity and reuse the password ? if yes , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074910/5751404) may help .

Comment: Thx. this will help